# How to select top 20 rows from a dataset in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataSet ds = gn.fillGrid_with_param_DAL("Allotment_Distribution_view", paramchk);

grd_Search.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Select("Top 20");
grd_Search.DataBind();
```

I want to get top 20 rows from the dataset. In my dataset I am getting records from database. I just need to select top 20 rows. Above is my code that I am trying to bind top 20 rows to my grid but I am getting error as

```
missing operand after 20
```

Comment: can you show us full query

Answer (score 1):

```
dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(n)
```

this will be helpful

else use this  LINQ:

```
dt.Table[0].AsEnumerable().Take(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(20);
```

I don't know what `gn` is, but if you're getting this data from a database, I'd suggest modifying your query so you only pull back the data you need. It'll be faster than pulling back everything and then only using 20 records on the client side.

In DB2, it'd be `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`. For Oracle, look into [rownum](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/top_records.php). I think for MSSQL it's something like `SELECT TOP n FROM...` You'll have to use an equivalent Order By clause with each of those to make sure the records you want are the first results.

Comment: According to MSSQL: you  can also use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I tried that but for fetching even 20 rows it is taking 19 odd seconds.

Comment: @Ankur: Then your view is slow. Here is an example: `WITH X AS(SELECT RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY OrderCol ASC),OtherCols FROM Table WHERE ...)SELECT X.* FROM X WHERE RN BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow`.

Comment: @Grant Winney : I used it , but now it is giving me error when Grid.Databind() line occurs, saying the coumn doesnt exist. This is happening because ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(20); line is giving results in datable and there is no column with the specified name.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : can you please explain me the query. I am new to such kind of programming.

Comment: @Ankur: Sorry, comments are not the best place to explain this. You might want to read this (for example): http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/how-does-paging-work-with-row-number-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

If .net framework 3.5 and above, use this:

> DataTable dtTop = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast().Take(20).CopyToDataTable();

If .net framework 2.0, do a for loop, here is a sample to copy rows from table to table using ImportRow method: http://alisissa.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/this-row-already-belongs-to-another-table/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to solve your problem in the wrong place.

To prevent loading all of your (possibly unbounded) records into memory (as e.g. "AsEnumerable" will do), I suggest you solve this at your data layer. I.e. ensure that you can specify the amount of top records to take as an argument in the call to `fillGrid_with_param_DAL` as:

```
DataSet ds = gn.fillGrid_with_param_DAL("Allotment_Distribution_view", paramchk, 20);
```

Most databases support taking a "top n" of records in a query.

For TSQL (SQL Server):

```
 SELECT TOP(5) Model, Color, Price
 FROM dbo.Cars
 WHERE Color = 'red';
```

For SQLite:

```
SELECT Model, Color, Price
FROM CARS 
WHERE Color = 'red'
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In framework 3.5, `dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(n)` or in earlier you can use

```
  public DataTable  SelectTopDataRow(DataTable dt, int count)
    {
         DataTable dtn = dt.Clone();
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         {
             dtn.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
         }

         return dtn;
    }
```